# What is the performance difference between aws EC2 shared, dedicated instance and dedicated host?

Tags: amazon-ec2, performance, dedicated-server, shared-hosting

I searched the web, but I did not get any information in terms of performance of your application in EC2 for each type of tenancy - shared, dedicated instance and dedicated host. The information that I got is what is mentioned on aws website. Aws website does not mention about performance of these tenancy. From the document I read, it seems aws guarantees the capacity, but it does not guarantee the performance. I am particularly interested in finding out what is the performance of all the EC2 tenancy, shared tenancy in particular.

Comment: I believe there is *meant* to be no performance difference. The main difference is compliance.

Answer (score 1):

It will be different between instsnce types, sizes, tenancies, loads (cpu vs network vs storage), etc.

Your best bet is to **benchmark your actual workload** on different instances and decide what *cost/performance ratio* makes the most sense for you.

That’s the only relevant answer to your question. Without the actual benchmark of your workload you’re only going to get opinions, hearsays and irrelevant misleading stats.

Hope that helps :)